# how can i insert a new Integer into the list , when the list is sorted?

Tags: list, hyperlink, sorting

i want to insert an new element ( Integer ) into a sorted linked list without change the order e.g :
if linkedlist like this : 4 --> 6 --> 8-->10 
and after calling the the method sortedl(7) , the linkedlist will be : 
4-->6-->7-->-->**8**-->10

I've tried writing a code, but it always adds it after number six !

any idea?

Comment: What code have you tried? Posting what you've tried helps us a lot with answering your question. And I don't think I quite understand your question. Where is it that you want your element inserted into the linked list, if not after number six?

Comment: @BurningLights is right, this question is quite confusing. Can you elaborate more and maybe post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You traverse your linked list until you encounter a node that is greater than the number you want to insert.  Let's call that note N+1.  I'm going to call the node before that N-1.  The name is fairly arbitrary.

You create a new node, let's call it N, that represents your new number (7 in the example).

Before the insert, node N-1 (holding the value 6) is pointing to node N+1 (holding the value 8).

To insert, you point N-1 to N, and point N to N+1.  If this is a double linked list, you update the back pointers in a similar manner.

> I've tried writing a code, but it always adds it after number six !

If your input value is 7 (from `sortedI(7)`), that is indeed what you want to see happen as 6 < 7 < 8.  However if that happens for any input value, post your code.